# Expand/Collapse List in HTML with JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Friends, I am working on **JavaScript** for collapse/Expand `<UL>` list.
here is my [Code](http://jsfiddle.net/4zdfe3fa/1/). I am wanted to work on it, in Nth Level, i can show Child, but its not hiding Children.
 I hope you guys will help me..
Thanks in Advance...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will do the trick:

```
event.stopPropagation();
```

[Docs](http://api.jquery.com/event.stoppropagation/).

If you debug your code you'll see that the event is being called for each parent `ul`. Check this out:

```
$("#ExpList ul li:has(ul)").click(function(event) { 
    event.stopPropagation();

    $(this).find('> ul')
        .toggleClass("hiddenChild")
        .toggleClass("displayChild"); 
});
```

And the HTML:

```
<div id='ExpList'>
    <ul>
        <li>Platform-1
            <ul class='hiddenChild'>
                <li>Child-1
                    <ul class='hiddenChild'>
                        <li>P-C-C-1</li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4zdfe3fa/4/).

HTML considerations:

- I don't know if you can use a `div` wrapping the whole list, but I think it would make more sense doing it;
- You're using the id `ExpList` for all `ul`. This is not how we use an `id`. Instead, for selecting many elements use its own tag or a common class;
- I removed the `onClick = openChild()` which were present in all `ul`. It was throwin an error in your fiddle.

JavaScript considerations:

- You don't have to mix a selector with a find this way `$("#ExpList").find('li:has(ul)')`. You can just use it on the same selector, as I did `$("#ExpList ul li:has(ul)")`;
- You don't need to search for all `ul` children(`$(this).children('ul')`) since you'll have just one, I used this instead, which looks for just one: `$(this).find('> ul')`;
- As said before, the `event.stopPropagation()` does the trick. You don't need to trigger `click` event on all parent `ul`.

In CSS, I just changed `#ExpList` to this `#ExpList ul` to work in the new structure. I hope it helps.

Comment: Let's say I have content within the `<li>` tags, how can I make it so that the toggle only is triggered by say clicking an `<a>` element within the `<li>`?